# How to open a port in Centos

Tags: centos, iptables, port

I would like to use my `iptables` file like this.

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
 # Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
 *filter
 :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
 :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
 :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
 :FIREWALL - [0:0]

 -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

 -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

 # Global

 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9117 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9118 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9119 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9116 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -j DROP

 -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
 -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
 COMMIT
```

But after I type `netstat -anlp` to check which ports were open, I don't see port 9119,9117,9116 open.
Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

netstat will only show ports that are being listened to by an active process, it does not report on those that are open through the firewall.

Check that your program that is listening is up and running

Answer (score 0):

As @Phil suggested you need to have the specific service on your server up and listening to connections to see it on `netstat -anlp`  output.

To verify if the said ports are open in firewall you can check the output of `iptables -L`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check that the ports are open you can use nmap:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap

Otherwise, like said above, ensure your services are started prior to checking netstat for activity on those ports.